# If two Jewish sisters marry one's son to one's daughter, are their descendants all mamzerim forever?

Tags: halacha, marriage, mamzer

I've heard that the children of two sisters are like siblings spiritually. If a woman gives her son to marry her sister's daughter this is forbidden, correct?

Does this make the union incest and the children of such a union mamzerim? Even if it was very common to marry cousins in the shtetls of Europe?

But the first-cousins who married -- their mothers were sisters.

1. Halachically, are the children of such unions mamzerim?
2. If a mamzer is unaware of his or her status and marries a regular Jew and has children with this Jew, are their children mamzerim?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Temima. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Can you source _I've heard that the children of two sisters are like siblings spiritually_? Never heard of that.

Comment: Your second question is unrelated to your first question, and therefore should probably be asked in a separate post.

Answer (score 9):

Marriage between first cousins are allowed in Judaism.

[aish.com](http://www.aish.com/atr/Cousin-Marriages.html) writes explicitly

> **It is permitted under Torah law for cousins to marry.** In fact, the
>   Sages seem to view marriages between relatives as desirable. The
>   Talmud recommends that a person marry his niece (Yevamot 62b).
>   [...] The assumption is that a
>   person will have an especially close relationship with a close
>   relative, perhaps because of their likely similar personalities and
>   values. The reasoning may be the same for a cousin, but the Talmud
>   doesn't mention it. (I should point out that for a woman to marry her
>   nephew is forbidden from the Torah – Leviticus 18:12-13.)
>
> Some point out that the daughters of Zelophehad married their cousins
>   (Numbers 36:11) so the practice has good precedent. [...]
>
> In terms of the genetic issues, [...] relatives who marry
>   should be even more careful to do genetic screening in advance.

Note that a number of countries and US states [forbid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin_marriage#United_States_2) first-cousin marriage though.

*[Mamzerim](https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/the-mamzer-problem/)* are the children of an adulterous or incestuous union (e.g., a man and a married woman or of a brother and sister - but NOT of a man to to an unmarried woman). Any decisions on the status of their children need to be considered by a qualified rabbi as there might be ways to disqualify the marriage (e.g., on technical grounds) and avoid the *mamzer* status.

Answer (score 3):

received an answer from Rabbi David Sperling of yeshiva.co:

> Shalom,  Thank you for your question. First cousins are allowed to
>   marry according to Jewish law. The children of two sisters (i.e. first
>   cousins) are permitted to marry, and therefore there is no question at
>   all of any mamzer status applying. [However one should be aware that
>   there are genetic issues involved in such a marriage – and one would
>   be advised to seek genetic testing etc before such a union.] I am
>   unaware of any source that equates cousins of siblings.
>
> In regards to your second question – the law is that an unknown (or
>   even doubtful) mamzer is not a mamzer at all. That is, it is not that
>   they are an “unknown mamzer”, but one of the laws of a mamzer is that
>   until the mamzer status is clarified beyond doubt, there is no mamzer
>   at all.

Thank you to all who responded!